# spreadsheet gem error accessing multiple sheets of a excel file

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to access multiple sheets of a excel file at a time and facing issue, below is the code

```
sheetname1 ="sheet1"
sheetname1 ="sheet2"
book = Spreadsheet.open(file_name)

sheet1 = book.worksheets.find { |sheet| sheet.name == sheetname1 } 
sheet2 = book.worksheets.find { |sheet| sheet.name == sheetname2 } 
5.upto(sheet2.rows.count) do |findrownum|
  0.upto(sheet2.column_count) do |findcolnum|
  end
end
```

error which i am getting is , not sure why it is not able to read sheet2

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `rows' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you see what `book.worksheets.map(&:name)` prints?

Comment: it print the sheet names and i can see the sheetname in the output, so the sheet exist only problem is that it not able to read multiple sheets at a time

Comment: @testerBDD : check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

silly mistake, you have not taken `sheetname2` variable, check your code:

```
sheetname1 ="sheet1"
sheetname1 ="sheet2" # should be sheetname2
```

---

> NoMethodError: undefined method `rows' for nil:NilClass

read error properly, your `sheet2` seems `nil`

You can access worksheet of workbook with `index` or `name`

for eg:

```
  sheet1 = book.worksheets sheetname1
  sheet2 = book.worksheets sheetname2

  # to avoid above error, you can add if condition to check
  if sheet2
    5.upto(sheet2.rows.count) do |findrownum|
      0.upto(sheet2.column_count) do |findcolnum|
      end
    end
  end
```

for more info:
https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md#reading-is-easy

Comment: both the sheets exist if i use only one sheet (either sheet1 or sheet2) it works but if i want to use both the sheets at a same time it is failing

Comment: @testerBDD : i have test in my local, working fine.. got output `sheet1.rows.count => 362` and `sheet2.rows.count  => 37 `